# how to use GCMV in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, garbage-collection

All in the title.

I just found this plugin in Eclipse to evaluate my WebApp running on a tomcat6 server. After I open the perspective `GCMV` and turn on the server, it shows nothing at all.

I've done some search about `GCMV tutorial Eclipse` etc. But didn't find anything interesting.

Well I know I'm such an idiot, so can someone give some instructions about how to use it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

GCMV doesn't work on a running JVM. It is used offline after the application finishes.

To use it, do the following:

1. Add the following VM argument to your command line to generate a gc log file:

   `-verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -Xloggc:[log file location]`
2. From GCMV perspective use File->Load File... with the file generated in step 1.

Answer (score 5):

When in the GCMV perspective, you should Open the File menu and use Load File ...

The chart will show up in the center panel.

You should see a templates panel on the left side which items let you switch between charts.

Comment: Thank you, could you please add some screetshots? What format of file is it loading? It can't connect to the JVM dynamically?